# React Hooks: useState with onClick only updating the SECOND time button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

Edit: forgot an important part - this is noticeable if you click the button next to Jeff A. Menges and check the console log.

The important part of the code is the "setFullResults(cardResults.data.concat(cardResultsPageTwo.data))" line in the onClick of the button code. I think it SHOULD set fullResults to whatever I tell it to... except it doesn't work the first time you click it. Every time after, it works, but not the first time. That's going to be trouble for the next set, because I can't map over an undefined array, and I don't want to tell users to just click on the button twice for the actual search results to come up.

I'm guessing useEffect would work, but I don't know how to write it or where to put it. It's clearly not working at the top of the App functional component, but anywhere else I try to put it gives me an error.

I've tried "this.forceUpdate()" which a lot of places recommend as a quick fix (but recommend against using - but I've been trying to figure this out for hours), but "this.forceUpdate()" isn't a function no matter where I put it.

Please help me get this button working the first time it's clicked on.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const App = () => {

  let artistData = require("./mass-artists.json");

  const [showTheCards, setShowTheCards] = useState();
  const [fullResults, setFullResults] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFullResults();
  }, []);

  let artistDataMap = artistData.map(artistName => {
    //console.log(artistName);
    return (
      <aside className="artist-section">
        <span>{artistName}</span>
        <button
          className="astbutton"
          onClick={ function GetCardList() {
            fetch(
              `https://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?unique=prints&q=a:"${artistName}"`
            )
              .then(response => {
                return response.json();
              })
              .then((cardResults) => {
                console.log(cardResults.has_more)
                if (cardResults.has_more === true) {
                fetch (`https://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?unique=prints&q=a:"${artistName}"&page=2`)
                .then((responsepagetwo) => {
                  return responsepagetwo.json();
                })
                .then(cardResultsPageTwo => {
                  console.log(`First Results Page: ${cardResults}`)
                  console.log(`Second Results Page: ${cardResultsPageTwo}`)
                  setFullResults(cardResults.data.concat(cardResultsPageTwo.data))
                  console.log(`Full Results: ${fullResults}`)
                })
                }
                setShowTheCards(
                  cardResults.data
                  .filter(({ digital }) => digital === false)
                  .map(cardData => {
                    if (cardData.layout === "transform") {
                      return (
                        //TODO : Transform card code
                        <span>Transform Card (Needs special return)</span>
                      )
                    }
                    else if (cardData.layout === "double_faced_token") {
                      return (
                        //TODO: Double Faced Token card code
                        <span>Double Faced Token (Needs special return)</span>
                      )
                    }
                    else {
                      return (
                        <div className="card-object">
                          <span className="card-object-name">
                          {cardData.name}
                          </span>
                          <span className="card-object-set">
                          {cardData.set_name}
                          </span>
                          <img
                          className="card-object-img-sm"
                          alt={cardData.name}
                          src={cardData.image_uris.small}
                          />
                        </div>
                      )
                    }
                  })
                )
              });
          }}
        >
          Show Cards
        </button>

      </aside>
    );
  });

  return (
    <aside>
      <aside className="artist-group">
      {artistDataMap}
      </aside>
      <aside className="card-wrapper">
      {showTheCards}
      </aside>
    </aside>
  );
};

export default App;
```

CodesAndBox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/compassionate-satoshi-iq3nc?fontsize=14

Comment: loads result every-time I click, show us an example to reproduce.

Comment: Sorry, tired - click the button next to Jeff A. Menges and check the console log.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce on Click of Jeff A. Menges.

Comment: You are accessing the fullResults immediately after setting up state, check fullresults in render it should have latest value.

Comment: your console.log statement call first then setState.

`useEffect(() => {
    console.log(fullResults);
    setFullResults();
  });
`

Comment: your click is working, your fullResults state will get updated value in next render not just after setting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try refactoring the code like for onClick handler have a synthetic event. Add this event Listener as part of a class. Use arrow function so that you need not bind this function handler inside the constructor. After fetching the data try to set the state to the result and use the state to render the HTML mark up inside render method. And when I run this code, I have also seen one error in console that child elements require key attribute. I have seen you are using Array.prototype.map inside render method, but when you return the span element inside that try to add a key attribute so that when React diffing algorithm encounters a new element it reduces the time complexity to check certain nodes with this key attribute.

Answer (score -1):

```
useEffect(() => {
   // call the functions which depend on fullResults here
   setFullResults();
}, [fullResults])
```

// now it will check whether **fullResults** changed, if changed than call functions inside **useEffect** which are depending on **fullResults**